# DCM ignoring my gclid conversion

Tags: double-click-advertising

I'm using a GCLID that I generated,

My code:

```
floodlight_config_id = rulerFloodlight['floodlightConfigurationId']

conversion = {
    'gclid': encrypted_user_id,
    'floodlightActivityId': rulerFloodlight['id'],
    'floodlightConfigurationId': floodlight_config_id,
    'ordinal': '0',  # this is to enable deduplication
    'timestampMicros': conversion_timestamp
}

request_body = {'conversions': [conversion]}

request = service.conversions().batchinsert(profileId=profile_id,
                                            body=request_body)
```

This worked when using the encrypted user id but seems to fail when using a gclid.

I have a version for DCS aswell that will not accept my gclid for some reason,

This is all paired to the correct advertiser which is associated with the gclid being generated

Doubleclick seem to have very limited documentation as the error I'm receiving is a [NOT_FOUND](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-advertisers/core_errors#NOT_FOUND) error.

My error message is :`'message': u"GCLID '<GCLID>' can not be found."`

Answer (score -1):

Many of the rules for uploading/modifying historical conversions changed recently. It may be that the GCLID you're referencing is older than a year.

You'll find more information under the "Can I upload historical conversions?" section of [this About](https://support.google.com/ds/answer/3465926?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was previously using `user encryption id` which has now been removed and as the [documentation states](https://support.google.com/ds/answer/7384231) I should be able to use the click_id to upload the conversion to the DCM api, the GCLID I was using was only a few hours old.